# Does a delphi application on IIS utilize the web.config

Tags: delphi, iis, web-config

We have some config in the web.config such as maxReceivedMessageSize

Are properties like these only utilized in ASP.net applications, or would they also be utilized by delphi applications if they were hosted from IIS under the corresponding site with the web.config?

Comment: the answer would be no, Delphi has nothing to do with ASP/ASP.NET.

Comment: Do you have any idea how you would configure such filters for Delphi applications on an IIS server?

Comment: It depends on what technology is being used in the delphi application? CGI/ISAPI, intraweb, ...

Comment: As Delphi doesn't have any connection to the .NET platform (specifically ASP.NET web applications) it is extremely unlikely that any Delphi app would utilise the `web.config` file. Having said that, you could easily write a Delphi server side application that reads some (or all) of its configuration values from the `web.config` file as it's just an XML file.

Comment: I think it is using ISAPI